# Send message in specific partition of Topic

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

Is there any way producer could send messages to specific partiton of topic in broker ?

As of now, am able to send topic having 2 partitions, but dont have control to send in specific partition.

```
Component
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class RsvpsKafkaProducer {
  
    private static final int SENDING_MESSAGE_TIMEOUT_MS = 10000;

    private final Source source;

    public RsvpsKafkaProducer(Source source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public void sendRsvpMessage(WebSocketMessage<?> message) {
        
         System.out.println("sendRsvpMessage");
         source.output()
                .send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(message.getPayload())
                        .build(),
                        SENDING_MESSAGE_TIMEOUT_MS);   
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes=localhost:2181
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=localhost:9093

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=meetupTopic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.partitionCount=2

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.content-type=text/plain
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.headerMode=raw
```

Is there any way I could achieve it using spring cloud stream ? I want some messages to go in `P1` partition and some to `P2` partition within `meetupTopic`.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using groups ?

Comment: @jr593, meaning ?

Comment: What is this message builder class? Could you give some details on that? The ProducerRecord from kafka can directly be provided the partition you want to send it to, so there are chances that the MessageBuilder should be exposing the same functionality in some way.

Comment: @RishabhSharma, https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/support/MessageBuilder.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```java
MessageBuilder.withPayload(message.getPayload())
                        .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.PARTITION_ID, 23)
                        .build()
```

Comment: Is there any way I could pass some custom partition name, and if not exists, will be created ?

Comment: See https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.0.8.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_streambridge_and_dynamic_destinations

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but from the [docs](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/2.1.0.RC1/multi/multi__partitioning_with_the_kafka_binder.html), it looks like it might work.

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.partitionSelectorExpression=headers['partitionKey']
```

And then you add the header `partitionKey` when you send the message.

Comment: That will work, but it needs `partitioned=true` and it's meant for more complex application level partitioning - it's simpler to just set the `KafkaHeaders.PARTITION_ID` header. Which is the default mechanism used by the underlying spring-integration-messaging infrastructure.

Comment: Nice solution Gary, I was looking for something like that but couldn't find it.